# DateUtils getRelativeTimeSpanString isn't returning time in "X seconds ago"

Tags: java, android, android-dateutils

I am using the getRelativeTimeSpanString(...) to get time back in `X seconds ago` `X hours ago` etc.

However, when the difference between the two times is short - minutes or seconds, then it is returning `in 10 hours` instead of `X minutes ago`

Here is how I'm using it:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                .parse("2014-05-21 13:07:11");
Date currentDate = new Date();
CharSequence cs =  DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date.getTime(), 
                                 currentDate.getTime(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
```

Comment: it means that the differences between the two are negative (so it read it as future) And you can use System.currentTimeMillis() instead of currentDate = new Date()

Comment: dope...you are right. The time on my emulator was wrong. I'll keep the question open in-case someone else goes through this :)

Comment: It might be an issue of `TimeZone`.